# How to redirect to a specific tab using Laravel

Tags: laravel, tabs

I am using the Laravel application for my project where I have 3 different tabs in a view.

**The tabs on view file-**

```
<a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="pill" href="#tab1">tab1 </a>
<a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#tab2">tab2</a>
<a class="nav-link" data-toggle="pill" href="#tab3">tab3</a>
```

Now, I have a form and I want to redirect to a specific tab after submitting it.

**In Controller, I am returning like this-**

```
 return redirect()->route('home')->with('message','sucessfull');
```

Now, I don't know how to redirect to a specific tab. Can you please help me to know it?

Comment: I don't know if its cool to post a link here, but I wrote an article https://talltips.novate.co.uk/tabbed-content-using-alpine-js#use-hashtags-to-allow-any-tab-to-be-opened-directly

Answer (score 0):

To redirect to a specific tab, you have to use URL hash.

For Tab 1-

```
return redirect(route('home').'#tab1')->with('message','sucessfull');
```

For Tab 2-

```
return redirect(route('home').'#tab2')->with('message','sucessfull');
```